# If two dice are thrown 5 times what is the probability that sum of the numbers coming up will be 10 in exactly 5 out of these 5 trials.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know there can be 3 possible pairs, so we have 1/12 possibilities to toss one of them.  But I'm not sure how to prove it for 5 out of 5 times.

Answer (score 4):

You want a ten on **all five tosses**, which are independent, so the probabilities multiply. The answer is $\frac1{12^5}$.